# JSON SQL field and JSON_CONTAINS how execute raw SQL query with Laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a json array like:

```
users => json_encode(array[1,2,3,4]);
```

So i tried this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user_conversations WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(users, JSON_ARRAY(1))
```

and it's works but I have no idea how to make this query in Laravel.

Comment: You will need to use `whereRaw()` method.

Comment: But please make sure you really want to keep your data this way, instead of having separate records for each relation.

Comment: thanks a lot @RoboRobok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **[Laravel Database: Query Builder Raw Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-methods)**

> #### whereRaw / orWhereRaw
>
> The **whereRaw** and **orWhereRaw** methods can be used to inject a raw where clause into your query. These methods accept an optional array of bindings as their second argument:
>
> ```php
> $orders = DB::table('orders')
>                ->whereRaw('price > IF(state = "TX", ?, 100)', [200])
>                ->get();
> ```

So I Solved my problem by using the `whereRaw` method:

```php
DB::table('user_conversations')->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(users, JSON_ARRAY(1))')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```